How to configure screenshot tool in ubuntu to snip area on mouse release?
I am trying to replicate the way windows snipping tool behaves on ubuntu 22.04
from my understanding, gnome-screenshot is ubuntu's default screenshotting tool.
When using the "selection" tool it's possible to select an area on screen and press the "capture" gui button to take the area snip.
It's annoying to me to have to specifically press that capture button. I would like the snipping tool to take that snip on mouse release (after selecting an area, just like windows) instead...
I would have been fine with it if numpad-enter would have worked too but it seems that only the regular large enter can trigger the capture for me.
Are there any settings (or alternative snipping tool) that allows to capture the selected area on mouse release?

You've not provided your Ubuntu release details; and gnome-screenshot is not installed for all releases as its not the default tool unless you're asking about a rather old release. What Ubuntu release are you asking about?  (gnome-screenshot was a GTK3 tool, and GNOME has been GTK4 for some time now, including the last two LTS releases)

I am on 22.04 - I see that gnome-screenshot isn't available on this system so what you're saying makes sense. I am not sure what the default screenshot tool is then

It is best to test and choose the tool yourself, a recommendation may be heelpful but you might not get one. This might be helpful https://www.tecmint.com/take-or-capture-desktop-screenshots-in-ubuntu-linux/

It is not possible to have the new screenshot tool make a screenshot as soon as you release the mouse. You either have to click the button, or hit the Enter key. Also Space will work the same.
To take a screenshot of a selection in the way you would prefer, you can install the old gnome-screenshot tool. You can change the existing keyboard bindings to use the old tools if you wish. In "Settings - Keyboard - Keyboard shortcuts", disable the ones under the section "Screenshots" and create custom shortcuts on these keyboard binding that contain the gnome-screenshot command with the appropriate flags.
